# Move one folder to another in Google Colab through code

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, I want to move one folder inside another. E.g. move child_folder parent_folder.
I am able to drag the child_folder to parent_folder, but when I try the below command, I get the error: **/bin/bash: move: command not found**

`!move child_folder parent_folder`

Is there any command for this in Google Colab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to move files is `mv` rather than `move`. So, write instead:

`!mv chold_folder parent_folder`